# JSF1.1 Webapp on WebSphere AS 7 IntrospectionException

Tags: spring, jsf, facelets, websphere-7

Got an exception during migration Web application from WAS 6.1 to WAS 7. This application developed using JSF1.1 (MyFaces) + Facelets + Spring (for backing beans). On some pages I'm getting the following exception:

```
Caused by: javax.faces.FacesException: Could not retrieve value of component with path : {Component-Path : [Class: javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot,ViewId: /pages/recovery_accs.xhtml][Class: javax.faces.component.html.HtmlForm,Id: sequestration][Class: javax.faces.component.html.HtmlDataTable,Id: _id37][Class: javax.faces.component.UIColumn,Id: _id50][Class: javax.faces.component.html.HtmlOutputText,Id: _id52]}

    at org.apache.myfaces.shared_impl.renderkit.RendererUtils.getValue(RendererUtils.java:271)

    at org.apache.myfaces.shared_impl.renderkit.RendererUtils.getStringValue(RendererUtils.java:226)

    at org.apache.myfaces.shared_impl.renderkit.html.HtmlTextRendererBase.renderOutput(HtmlTextRendererBase.java:69)

    at org.apache.myfaces.shared_impl.renderkit.html.HtmlTextRendererBase.encodeEnd(HtmlTextRendererBase.java:57)

    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:799)

... 46 more

Caused by: javax.faces.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /pages/sub/idocAccsRecoverySub.xhtml @34,55 value="#{varbean.idocAcc.vzOrder}": Bean: com.test.project.bean.idoc.accs.IdocAccBean, property: idocAcc

    at com.sun.facelets.el.LegacyValueBinding.getValue(LegacyValueBinding.java:58)

    at javax.faces.component.UIOutput.getValue(UIOutput.java:118)

    at org.apache.myfaces.shared_impl.renderkit.RendererUtils.getValue(RendererUtils.java:267)

    ... 50 more

Caused by: java.beans.IntrospectionException: Parameter type in setter method does not corresponds to predefined.

    at java.beans.PropertyDescriptor.setWriteMethod(Unknown Source)

    at java.beans.PropertyDescriptor.<init>(Unknown Source)

    at java.beans.StandardBeanInfo.introspectProperties(Unknown Source)

    at java.beans.StandardBeanInfo.<init>(Unknown Source)

    at java.beans.Introspector.getBeanInfoImpl(Unknown Source)

    at java.beans.Introspector.getBeanInfoImpl(Unknown Source)

    at java.beans.Introspector.getBeanInfoImplAndInit(Unknown Source)

    at java.beans.Introspector.getBeanInfo(Unknown Source)

    at org.apache.myfaces.el.PropertyResolverImpl.getPropertyDescriptor(PropertyResolverImpl.java:474)

    at org.apache.myfaces.el.PropertyResolverImpl.getProperty(PropertyResolverImpl.java:438)

    at org.apache.myfaces.el.PropertyResolverImpl.getValue(PropertyResolverImpl.java:85)

    at com.sun.facelets.el.LegacyELContext$LegacyELResolver.getValue(LegacyELContext.java:141)

    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:123)

    at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:186)

    at com.sun.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:71)

    at com.sun.facelets.el.LegacyValueBinding.getValue(LegacyValueBinding.java:56)

    ... 52 more
```

Tried to use different version of facelet library and different EL implementations. Even tried to recompile project using IBM's JDK. Still no success. On Apache Tomcat it works without problem.

In a stacktrace above - **IdocAccBean** is a regular java bean which extends an abstract class **IdocAccCore**. If I use other backing beans which extend that class I get the same exception. All other beans not derived from   **IdocAccCore** work correctly.  There is nothing special in **IdocAccCore** class and it's pretty big so I don't think it's necessary to give full source code.

Any suggestions what can be wrong with that  **IdocAccCore** class?

Comment: More details - it seems that this problem is about runtime environment. I tried to run my webapp under Apache Tomcat using IBMs JRE and got the same problem. With SUN's JRE everything works fine. Also I've found that I can't  access to any properties in my IdocAccBean class with valid get and set methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem solved by updating IBMs version of JRE. Actually, I was thinking that I'm using the latest version of IBMs JRE. For sure I downloaded one from IBM's site[IBM Development Package for Eclipse](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/jdk/eclipse/index.html). The problem is that this package contains pretty old version of IBM's java 1.6.  Fresh version of IBM's java I found in fixpacks for Websphere AS.
You can find detailed list of fixed bugs in IBM's java 1.6 [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/jdk/aix/j632/Java6.fixes.html)